# Não consigo acessar uma página de formulário

Tags: java, spring

Estou fazendo um curso do Alura de Spring framework, porém não consigo acessar uma página de formulário através do link http://localhost:8080/casadocodigo/produtos/form. Dá o seguinte erro:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>   Type Status Report
>
> Message /casadocodigo/produtos/WEB-INF/views/produtos/form.jsp
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.5

Creio eu que seja o caminho que está errado. Acho que não deveria ter esse `/produtos` entre o nome do projeto e `/WEB-INF`. É esse o problema? Por que ele está adicionando esse `/produtos`?

Segue o fonte do controller e da classe de configuração abaixo:

Classe ProdutosController:

```
package br.com.casadocodigo.loja.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.daos.ProdutoDAO;
import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.models.Produto;

@Controller
public class ProdutosController {

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoDAO produtoDao;

    @RequestMapping("/produtos")
    public String gravar(Produto produto) {
        System.out.println(produto);
        this.produtoDao.gravar(produto);
        return "produtos/ok";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/produtos/form")
    public String form() {
        System.out.println("Entrando em método FORM");
        return "produtos/form";
    }

}
```

Classe AppWebConfiguration:

```
package br.com.casadocodigo.loja.conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.controllers.HomeController;
import br.com.casadocodigo.loja.daos.ProdutoDAO;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={HomeController.class, ProdutoDAO.class})
public class AppWebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua jsp está dentro de uma pasta chamada `produtos`?

Comment: Sim. /WEB-INF/views/produtos/form.jsp Fiz um teste e alterei o @RequestMapping("/produtos/form") por @RequestMapping("/form") e consegui acessar o formulário. Pelo visto está dando conflito no mapeamento de url's parecidas. Pode me dizer se isso é para acontecer ou é normal? Pois segui exatamente como o instrutor fez.

Comment: Entendi o que aconteceu. Se no @RequestMapping eu colocar duas palavras separadas por "/" ele adiciona a anterior entre o nome do projeto e o /WEB-INF. Isso era pra acontecer? E se eu quiser montar uma url com mais de uma palavra como foi feito no curso que estou fazendo?

Comment: Não faz muito sentido. O Spring está preparado para lidar com urls com várias "/". Experimente colocar uma "/" no início da String na linha `resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/")`;

Comment: Colocar a "/" no início do prefixo deu certo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda cara!

Comment: @StatelessDev, o que acha de adicionar uma resposta já que resolveu o problema do Rubens? :)

Comment: @Dherik Me passou batido o comentário dele de que havido resolvido o problema. Obrigado por me alertar. Resposta criada.

Answer (score 1):

O Spring está preparado para lidar com urls com várias `"/"`. Modifique esta linha:

`resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");`

para

`resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");`